# Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria ----

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis, iis-7

I created custom authentication by Wcf after that I created self-sign ssl in IIS 7.5

and use below code in web.config

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="CN = srv-erp"/>
```

and this one too

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="CN = srv-erp"
                                storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                                storeName="My"/>
```

and I used FindBySerialNumber too.

but they didn't work and I get this error

> Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria:
> StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType
> 'FindBySubjectDistinguishedName', FindValue 'CN = srv-erp'.

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Open mmc, add the certificate snap-in for computer account, and at personal node check if your certificate is installed. Get its name and try to put in findValue.

Comment: I don't think you need to include the cn=, just add srv-erp as findValue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it seems that problem in the findValue property try to change it to serv-erp. You don't need to place key of property in findValue when you use  x509FindType.

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="srv-erp"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                            storeName="My"/>
```

Also you may try to find you certificate by another type ([see X509FindType reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509findtype(v=vs.110).aspx)) For instance, by thumbprint

```
<serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" 
                            findValue="b5 ca b7 d0 b8 da fd 20 b7 bb 14 5d 66 2b 53 f3 0c 20 ca f2"/>
```

Finally, ensure that your certificate is exist. Type **Run** in Search Windows  and copy and paste **certmgr.msc**. Then on the menu click on **Action -> Find certificates...**